# How to get the conflicted field name of ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I have a code like this

```
let item = { name: 'Roger' }

try {
   return await collection.save(item)
} 
catch (err) {

}
```

Now the collection I'm saving to has a Unique index on the field called `name`. Now during the exception handling the `err` object would look something like this

```
{
  "isArangoError": true,
  "response": {
    "_readableState": {
      "objectMode": false,
      "highWaterMark": 16384,
      "buffer": {
        "head": null,
        "tail": null,
        "length": 0
      },
      "length": 0,
      "pipes": [

      ],
      "flowing": true,
      "ended": true,
      "endEmitted": true,
      "reading": false,
      "sync": true,
      "needReadable": false,
      "emittedReadable": false,
      "readableListening": false,
      "resumeScheduled": false,
      "paused": false,
      "errorEmitted": false,
      "emitClose": true,
      "autoDestroy": false,
      "destroyed": false,
      "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
      "awaitDrainWriters": null,
      "multiAwaitDrain": false,
      "readingMore": true,
      "decoder": null,
      "encoding": null
    },
    "body": {
      "code": 409,
      "error": true,
      "errorMessage": "unique constraint violated - in index name_is_unique of type persistent over 'name'; conflicting key: 15816187",
      "errorNum": 1210
    },
    "arangojsHostId": 0
  },
  "statusCode": 409,
  "errorNum": 1210,
  "code": 409
}
```

While the error message is indeed helpful in conveying that `name` should be unique, wish there is an attribute/field in the error object to grab the conflicted field name.

How to get the field name other than regex parsing from the error message?